# Creating a custom build step for protobuffers in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create a custom build step and I've never done this before.

So I added the protoc.exe to the project directory. I then have in the command line

```
protoc --proto_path=proto --cpp_out=proto_files $(Identity)
```

where according to the macro evaluator it translates to the relative directory name of the file.

So this should evaluate to

```
protoc --proto_path=proto --cpp_out=proto_files proto/vector3.proto
```

or whatever the proto files name is

However I get a missing input file name error. Anyone know how to get this to work? My error is 'Missing input file'

Answer (score 0):

Derp.

Trick was to change $ to %. It works.